# Keybinding to go to an agenda custom view

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda

Running emacs 25.2.2 and org 9.1.13.

I have defined several custom views. I can visit them using `C-c a` followed by the assigned letter.

I was wondering if I could cut the dispatcher all together. I could, for instance, assign a key-binding to `org-agenda-list`.

Similarly, is there a way to assign a key-binding to a custom agenda view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `org-agenda` with an argument specifying what agenda to open: `(org-agenda nil "x")` does the same thing as `C-c a x`.  It can be bound to a key in any of the usual ways. For example to bind the "x" agenda to the F5 key:

```
(define-key (kbd "<f5>") 
            (lambda () 
             (interactive) 
             (org-agenda nil "x")))
```